# How to supply 2/p options to apportable command?

Tags: apportable

Currently, I need to type `2` and `p` for OpenGL ES 2.0 and portrait mode rendering when I run `apportable` command. Because I frequently erase all generated files to perform clean build.

Is there any way to supply these values automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally note that you can make the following bash script that will allow you to send 2 and p to apportable after having removed the generated files, if you choose to go that route (but as Paul said, those files are meant to be persistent -- if you are having troubles picking up changes to your xcodeproj, please let us know!):

```
echo "2
p
" | apportable
```

Answer (score 2):

**configuration.json** is meant to be a persistent file. If you keep it, you won't need to type the `2` and the `p`.

Some other related options:

- Use `apportable clean` to clean your build.
- Use `apportable --generate` to force build files to be regenerated.
- If for some reason `apportable clean` is not working, do `rm -rf ~/.apportable/SDK/Build/` to insure all objects get rebuilt.